# Database Server architecture for the availability of large amounts of historical information

Tags: mysql, database, architecture, scalability

We have a web service that allows a fixed number of users to view daily location data that gets collected and inserted every morning. We also allow access to the historical.

Our test environment includes two load balanced web servers, one master mysql, and two load balanced mysql slave servers. For development purposes this works fine, but that is only about 50 users working with the data at the same time.

We are having difficulty planning for the server architecture required to maintain uptime under the range of user load.
Our constraints are well known, including the amount of data that gets inserted daily.

What is the best architecture for us to design our system around considering our need to access historical data about < 10% of the time?

**What is known:**

- Our users are set at 125,000, with an estimation of 5,000 to 20,000 active daily, and that will not change.
- Our service collects about 5,760,000 records of information daily. (Can be condensed to about 120,000 daily records if we condense all the data into a daily table, which we were told is a big no no "so normalize it")
- Users can browse their historical information as much as they want, but they are typically only interested in their daily and weekly, monthly information.
- We don't need the data retrieval to be extremely fast
- Users can view historical data if they'd like (think weather underground, viewing temperatures from 1960)
- Our data aggregation is extremely predictable. We have up to 5 years worth of information so far at a DB size of roughly 80GB per year including index
- Although users extremely rarely access any data older than 1 year, we would still like to offer that ability.
- Users can opt in to receive email with their daily, weekly, and monthly information, so we will also process the data we get once a day to send emails.

**Test environment:**

We currently have a large ec2 instance with a standard 500gb ebs using mysql and innodb on all tables, with two small slaves for reads.
Our tables containing user information will be in a separate server.

- Is it feasible to have different database servers keep data from the current month in one, and historical data in another? Or is it better to just keep it in a separate table of the same server as the actively accessed data? We thought about having a separate small disk high memory database server for the months worth of active data (7GB), and as it becomes historical data, we move it to another server
- We have heard of clustering, but at the same time have also heard to stay the hell away from it unless all other options are exhausted.

Comment: "What is the best way architecture for us to design our system around considering our need to access historical data about < 10% of the time?" - hire a consultant.

Comment: For access to historical data less than 10% of the time? We don't need to access the data often, we just need to 'have' access to it when the user requests it.

Answer (score 1):

You design an operational database over how it will be accessed and used, not what needs to be stored, not "Well we might need...".

The relational model is wonderful for ad hoc queries, and playing what if scenarios. As load increases, and data sizes increase, these ad hoc one off queries become less, and less viable. Eventually, you can't afford them at all on the "production" server, as they inevitably interfere with production.

I mention this because you mentioned:

> Our service collects about 5,760,000 records of information daily. (Can be condensed to about 120,000 daily records if we condense all the data into a daily table, which we were told is a big no no "so normalize it")

If your users are only interested in the 120,000 summary records, then store the 5.7M rows someplace else. It's just taking up space and performance here. One nice, bad query can be an I/O bound, CPU pegging, DB cache smashing monster. Just what you don't want on your production system.

So, you need to base you design on what the users are querying for, what they really need, and how soon they need it. If the users can make asynchronous requests: "Hi, I'd like this historical query based on this criteria" then have them queue it up, and then send them an email when it's ready, or schedule daily, weekly, monthly jobs, as appropriate.

If you can keep your active data in 7GB a RAM, then that will be a big help. Do your slow, importing operations on your slow disk storage, send the summary data over to the RAM based system each night. Also, do not overlook SSD. SSD is very, very fast. Hard drives are the new tape drives.

As @BraveNewCurrency noted, 20,000 active users is not very meaningful, not is it a lot for simple queries. Is that over 24 hours? Does it spike from 9 to 5? Do they all surge in when the markets close? Tune for your peak load, and then some.

As for database size, if you're doing simple, indexed queries, with proper statistics, over small ranges, even against large tables, the overall size of the database is mostly meaningless. If you're doing "give me the 10 biggest things out of these 20M rows", then you're doomed. If queries like that are common and popular, they need special attention. Getting small portions out of indexes is quite fast. Doing large, summary sums, counts, averages and order bys on large datasets are ruinous. Even with row limits.

If you do:

```
SELECT ... FROM BIG_O_TABLE ORDER BY NON_INDEXED_COLUMN LIMIT 10
```

on a 20M row table, you'll sort that entire 20M row table. Every. Single. Time. And THEN get the 10 lowest rows.

So, you need to focus on your active queries that you make available to your users, and design around that. Work your procedures to ensure integrity if you're managing more that one database, and always archive and maintain the original raw data, so as to be able to rebuild the databases if you ever need to, especially if one goes down and gets out of sync with the other.

Comment: Will, I believe I explained the 'condensing' bit badly. The data we get comes in half hour intervals. What I meant to say is that instead of having it normalized, the table would have 48 collected-data related columns instead of just 1 per record, so 5,760,000/48 = 120,000. Regardless, It seems that in our case the db size isn't as important as the structure. If a problem will happen as data gets larger, the table structure or objective was wrong to begin with. Let me research our system a bit more and I'll respond to your other points.

Comment: And we can easily keep our active data in ram. 31 days worth of data is about 2.66075 GB. So far it seems that we are looking at a 'historical' db server with high disk capacity, and a high ram db server for the active data.

Answer (score 0):

> 20,000 active daily [users]

Hmm, even if each user has 10 hits per day, we're talking about an average of

```
20_000 users * 10 hits/day / (24*3600.0 seconds/day) = ~2 hits per second.
```

Your peak load will be 4x to 10x your average. So maybe you'll have 20 hits per second. What are you worried about again?

Comment: We are concerned that our current database implementation will rapidly degrade in performance with 5.7 million new daily records + 5 years of historical data. The webapp can easily handle the average of 2 hits per second like you stated, but we were under the (likely wrong) assumption that we would soon reach a point where the reads/write would degrade due to the increased size of the data in one server.